# Ford Taurus 2004 3.0

Tags: ford, sparkplugs, taurus, intake-manifold

I'm using MOTORCRAFT brand spark plugs, and would like to know the recommended  the gap for a 2004 Ford TAURUS 3.0.

Also, I have a a leak in the lower section of the intake manifold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do not have the SHO DOHC motor, Motorcraft SP413 spark plugs come pre-gapped at .044 inches, which is the OEM specification.

Your intake manifold leak is likely due to a gasket problem, but flatness should be checked on mating surfaces to make certain the gasket failure was not a result of warpage.